# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated from custom UITableView class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller

After user click on `cell` i do this after some of code:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
```

then when he hit cancel button or send in this method:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
[[((UIViewController *)(self.superview.superclass)) presentedViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

but my app crash and go out.

```
012-12-17 18:52:09.243 testapp[8293:15203] Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued
2012-12-17 18:52:09.243 testapp[8293:15203] +[UIResponder presentedViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbb5db0
2012-12-17 18:52:09.244 testapp[8293:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIResponder presentedViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbb5db0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ba6022 0x1688cd6 0x1ba7aad 0x1b0ced0 0x1b0ccb2 0x4e466 0xa99bf 0xac64f 0xa63f2 0x8d05af 0x1ba7e99 0x50f14e 0x50f0e6 0x5b5ade 0x5b5fa7 0x5b5266 0x5343c0 0x5345e6 0x51adc4 0x50e634 0x1d39ef5 0x1b7a195 0x1adeff2 0x1add8da 0x1adcd84 0x1adcc9b 0x1d387d8 0x1d3888a 0x50c626 0x370d 0x26c5 0x1)
```

Comment: build successful. but when run the app and try dismiss crash

Comment: self.superview.superclass - returns a class object. This object could not have view controller. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject)

Try just self.view.superview instead

Comment: However that kind od approach to dismis modal view controller is wrong. Try using delegates.

Comment: Property 'view' not found on object of type 'CustomTableView *'

Comment: Than it should be enough of self.superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  `[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

Try simply `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]`

Comment: if you read my question you will know this will give me an error.

Comment: it is custom tableview class so it will give me ( No visible @interface for 'CustomTableView' declares the selector 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:'

Comment: Well it is not exactly the same as `[[((UIViewController *)(self.superview.superclass)) presentedViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`. Try activating an exception breakpoint. What does it say on crash?

Comment: Well the message should be received by a View Controller, not by a View. BTW, you are casting `self.superview.superclass` to `UIViewController`. The superclass probably is a UIView. You can't make a cast to `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to dismiss from the VC then this should work:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: if you read my question you will know this will give me an error.

Comment: Please post the error/exception that gets printed to the log when the app crashes.

Comment: it is custom tableview class so it will give me ( No visible @interface for 'CustomTableView' declares the selector 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:'

Comment: Then wrap your custom tableview in a UITableViewController or a UIViewController. That way you will be able to dismiss it with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the crash is that presentedViewController only exists on iOS 5 and higher. If you run it on iOS 4 it causes the exception you have shown.

dismissModalViewController is the correct way to dismiss a controller presented with presentModalViewController for iOS 4+5. It still works on iOS 6 but is deprecated. There you presentViewController and dismissViewController instead.